# Android socket connection refused error

Tags: android, sockets

I want to implement socket connection between 2 deceives , client keep sending GPS data to the server and  I need both of it run in new thread , the client send first one data then keep show error like this

> 03-18 16:35:11.805: E/Client run:(8163): java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.2.103 (port 5678): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)

here is the client code

```
    public class Send implements Runnable{

    private boolean Connect = true;

    public void Connect(){
        Connect = true;
    }
    public void Disconnect(){
        Connect = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while(Connect){
            try {
                SocketClient = new Socket("192.168.2.103", 5678);
                ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(SocketClient.getOutputStream());
                oos.writeDouble(GPSinfo[2]);
                //ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(SocketClient.getInputStream());
                //ois.readInt();
                oos.close();
                //ois.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Client run: ", e.toString());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

here is server code

```
    public class Receive implements Runnable{
    private boolean CanReceive = true;
    private double Data;

    public void Connect(){
        CanReceive = true;
    }
    public void Disconnect(){
        CanReceive = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        while(CanReceive){
            try {
                SocketServer = new ServerSocket(5678);
                Socket connectedSocket = SocketServer.accept();
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(connectedSocket.getInputStream());
                Data = ois.readDouble();
                DataText.setText("" + Data);
                //ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(connectedSocket.getOutputStream());
                //oos.writeInt(1);
                //ois.close();
                //oos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Server run: ", e.toString());
            }

        }
    }

}
```

by the way , the both code is inner class , and INTERNET permission is added.

Comment: Your code does not compile. The line `SocketServer = new ServerSocket(5678);` is in error, or you have omitted the deciaration of `SocketServer` from the code you posted.

Answer (score 3):

It's obvious it's not a router-firewall related problem as you are under the same net, so there are only a few possibilities:

- There's nothing listening on that port on that IP on the server-side
- There's a local firewall on the server-side that is blocking that connection attempt
- You are not using WIFI so you're not under the same net.

You should make sure you can open that service some ther way, that would help you debugging where the culprit is. If you've already done this, I'd suggest using some debugging tool to trace TCP packets (I don't know either what kind of operating system you use on the destination machine; if it's some linux distribution, `tcpdump` might help, in Win environments `WireShark` works just good).

Comment: I am sure INTERNET permission is add in AndroidManifest.xml 
and my server can receive the first one data.

Comment: Then verify the rest of the possible issues, it must be one of them

Comment: I try useing WireShark capture like you mention , and yes , client can keep send data to me , mean connection is ok?

Comment: This means that the data sent from your client is (at least) reaching your server side (assuming you're using wireshark on the server side). That said, there must be something wrong on the server side, it can be either nothing listening on that port or a local firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: @Tony *Either* the connection was refused *or* data can reach the peer. You can't have it both ways.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't a 'data transfer error'. This is a 'connection refused' error. It means the server you want to transfer the data to or from isn't running at the IP:port you specified.

Your basic problem is that you are creating a new `ServerSocket` every time inside the loop, instead of using the same one for the life of the application.

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the adb service before you begin the connection. I had a similar problem and killing the adb service before the connection resolved the issue.

Comment: can you explain ? how can I do that

Answer (score -2):

I had the same error. I simply used ServerSocket and it worked well.

`ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8888);`

Comment: The OP is already using `ServerSocket`. Your answer explains nothing and answers nothing.